# How to store UserID in a class when they sing in?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to store the UserID in a global class as the user logs in to their account however i am getting an error.

error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'UserID'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '0'.'

Sign in button back-end code:

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username='" + tb_LoginUsername.Text + 
                "' AND Password='" + tb_LoginPassword.Text + "'UserID='"+User.UserID , sqlConnection) ;
            /* in above line the program is selecting the whole data from table and the matching it with the user name and password provided by user. */
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               User.UserID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());

               MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
               mainWin.Show();
               this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            }
```

class:

```
 class User
    {
        public static int UserID;
    }
```

Comment: 1. You have an unclosed quote at the end of the query. 2. Is the id *really* a string? 3. Absolutely don't ever ever use user input to form a query string! Use parameters. Your query will break with a password that has a quote in it, and worse your database will break if anyone does simple sql-injection.

Comment: @iakobski its not a string. Im just trying to get the userID so that i can use it after.

Comment: So it won't work with quotes round it then. But MOST OF ALL read my point 3 very carefully.

Comment: @iakobski ye i know all about that wham but that aint important for this at allll.

Comment: Change line 2 to `"' AND Password='" + tb_LoginPassword.Text + "' AND UserID="+User.UserID`

Comment: @iakobski so does that make it an interger.

Comment: You told me it's not a string

Comment: @iakobski well ye the UserID in the database is not a string and then you said is the ID really a string and i said no

Comment: So if it's not a string in the database, you don't need quotes round it. If you put quotes the query will fail. Here's a tip: assign the query you build to a variable. Put a breakpoint or print out the string to the console. Copy the string to your database query window and see if it runs. You will soon see how to fix it.

Comment: If you would just [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/) in your query this problem, and many others, will not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username='" + tb_LoginUsername.Text + 
                "' AND Password='" + tb_LoginPassword.Text + "'", sqlConnection) ;
            /* in above line the program is selecting the whole data from table and the matching it with the user name and password provided by user. */
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               User.UserID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());

               MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
               mainWin.Show();
               this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            }
```

removed :

```
"'UserID='"+User.UserID
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi well it fixed the code so ye u just do.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw you have `UserName` in your query already so `UserID` shouldn't have been there to begin with.

Comment: Here is a universal password for your application anyone can use for login. Enter any user name and for password enter `universal' or 1=1 --`. Instead of `universal`, you can actually use any other word too.